# Is there a way to force project members to use SSH-key based authentication instead of password based authentication for a project hosted on Gitlab?

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, ssh-keys

How can we enforce project members to use only SSH-key based authentication instead of password based authentication mechanism on Gitlab?

Is this possible through any Git settings or any options available on Gitlab that you can help me with?

*Any guidance on this subject is much appreciated. Thanks in advance..*

Comment: What' are you trying to achieve?  Are you okay with using personal access tokens instead of passwords or do you want to require SSH keys?

Comment: @bk2204 I want to force project members of my project to be able to clone, push and pull through ssh key based authentication only and not password based

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do what you want, but I'm not that familiar with GitLab.  I know that Git and GitHub don't offer such features.